# Custom Struct method can't set struct member

Tags: ruby

An example will explain the question:

```
Val = Struct.new(:value) do
  def inc 
    p value
    value = value + 1 
  end
end

v = Val.new(1)
v.inc
```

The output will be:

```
1
undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Why do I get this error when `value` is clearly not nil?  Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clarification on Sergio's answer.

Within `inc`'s definition, there is initially no variable `value`, and what is called by `p value` is the method `value`, which returns `1`.

Then in line `value = value + 1`, at the point when `value =` has been parsed, a local variable `value` is created and is initialized to `nil`. Even though `value + 1` is evaluated prior to assignment of its value into the newly created `value`, the initialization of `value` takes place first. So, when `value + 1` is to be evaluated, there already is a local variable `value`, which has priority to be called over the method `value`. And this value is `nil`.

Comment: my only remaining confusion is: why is "self." not implied as it normally is?  is that rule inapplicable to assignment statements in general?

Comment: If a method call (with implicit `self` receiver) had priority over a local variable, then there would be no way to call that variable.

Comment: well, it could work if you disallowed shadowing method names with local vars, right?  but i get your point

Answer (score 5):

```
Val = Struct.new(:value) do
  def inc 
    p value # here it still prints 1

    # but here you REDEFINED what value is. It is now a local variable!
    # Also its initial value is nil, hence the error you're getting.
    value = value + 1 

    # should have used this instead, to reference the method
    self.value = value + 1
  end
end
```